# binary string with random shift-cryptography

Tags: cryptography, bit-manipulation

Hello
I have a binary string length of n.My goal is that all bit in string will be equal to "1".
I can flip every bit of the string that I want but after fliping the bits of the string it does random circular shift.(shift length evenly distributed between 0...n-1)

I have no way to know what is a state of the bit not initianly nor in middle of process I only know when they all is "1"

As I understand there should be some strategy that guarantees me that I do all the permuatations in truth table of this string.

Thank you

Comment: If all bits are 1 then it's all just `0xfffffff...` which is probably not what you want. Can you elaborate a bit more? It's not clear ...

Comment: I have no knowledge of a initianal string value

Comment: What do you mean by random circular shift? Is the shift length evenly distributed between 0...n-1?

Comment: yes indeed the string can be shifted in any way it can

Answer (score 2):

Flip bit 1 until all are set to 1. I don't see there being anything faster without testing the bits.

Comment: I don't think its fastest strategy.There could be a situation that I wil take very long time to get the result I want.

Comment: @Evgeniy: Exactly. It could even be that you never reach that situation. But seeing the random shifting I doubt there's a way to make it faster unless you've got some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Georg has the best answer, if the string is shifted randomly (I assume by 0..n bits evenly distributed) his strategy of always flipping the first bit will sooner or later succeed.

Unfortunately that strategy may take very long time depending on the length of the string.

The expected value of the number of bits being set to 1 will be n/2 in average, so the probability that a bit flip will be successful is 0.5, for each bit being set that probability decreases by 1/n.

The process could be viewed as a [markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) where the probability for being at state 0xff...ff where all bits are set is calculcated and thus the number of trials in average required to reach that state can be calculated.